# Use GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can I use `GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction` in my Jenkins pipeline?
I tried:

```
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.*;
```

But it does not work:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 81: unable to resolve class GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction 
 @ line 81, column 34.
       GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction action = new GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction("star-gold.png");
```

I want to do a test with a shared library in my pipeline and using this snippet: https://gist.github.com/hayderimran7/7a49d0fa484f7561120b4190f8f3a888#file-retro-add-badges-groovy

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if you invoke the action for example

```
GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction action = new GroovyPostbuildSummaryAction('star-gold.png')
action.appendText('Comment line',false)
currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions().add(action)
```

The above works for me (we currently use GroovyPostBuild plugin 2.3.1)

Comment: Are you using something like this also in jenkins pipelines? I try to integrate it in a pipeline. I want to trigger another job from my pipeline, when that job succeeds I want to add a star to the build of my pipeline.

Comment: Jenkins pipelines work with the above code. Regarding your requirement if the supplementary job succeeds, say as a further pipeline stage, you can test for succesful completion
and add badge accordingly with:

    currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createBadge('star-gold.gif','badge text'))

The 'badge text' appears when you hover over the gif.